# How do I figure the true weekly cost of health insurance out of my paycheck if it's pre-taxed?

Tags: insurance

Obviously I know what the premium is, but if it's taken out pre tax then I won't be paying as much taxes on my paycheck every two weeks. The insurance is $556 a mo. but we only make $36k. $275+ each paycheck is a LOT to lose. Thank you.

Comment: Tax questions need a jurisdiction. What taxes are you paying from your paycheck?

Answer (score 5):

To find the amount that your paycheck will be lowered by, you just add back the taxes that are "saved" by having the premium lower your taxable income. If your total marginal tax rate (federal + state, or whatever applies where you're at) is `R` and your premium is `P`, then your paycheck will be lower by

```
P - (R*P)
```

or

```
P*(1-R)
```

So if your total marginal tax rate is 30% and your premium is $556, then your monthly take-home pay will be lower by `$556 * (1-0.30) = $389`.

If you're paid every two weeks, most likely you will have your pay reduced by 389/2 or $195 for 24 of the 26 weeks, and will have a higher paycheck in the two months that include the end of three biweekly periods (i.e 3 "paydays"). I call that the "bonus paycheck" since it does not include the monthly deductions. I budget based on the lower paycheck *every* two weeks and consider the extra in that third paycheck a "bonus"
and decide what to do with it then.

Note that your *marginal* rate is based on whatever tax bracket you should be in for the entire year, including all deductions and exemptions. It's not your tax withheld divided by the gross income; that's your *effective* tax rate.  it's possible that deducting health insurance could push you to a lower tax bracket, but since you're only estimating at this point anyway it should be good enough to use your current tax bracket.